# Extract Major and Minor from $(Build.SourceVersion)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my yaml pipeline, I have a task to scan my application in Black Duck but I need to provide the version number. Currently it's set to latest version, but when I build my artifacts in my CI, the build number increments by one (duh).

How do I do this by extracting from the `$(Build.SourceVersion)`

My goal is to only pass the Major and Minor version to Black Duck, but I need to do this in the yaml. Here is my step:

```
- task: SynopsysDetectTask@2
  displayName: "Run Black Duck analysis"
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.blackduck }}', 'true'))
  inputs:
    Products: 'BD'
    BlackDuckService: 'Black Duck'
    DetectVersion: 'latest'
    DetectArguments: '--detect.project.name=$(Build.Repository.Name)'
```

Comment: Just one confusing. `$(Build.SourceVersion)` represents commit id in azure devops. What do you need is extract major&minor value from commit id? Maybe what you point to is build id? Or build number?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT I realized this towards the end of the day yesterday. It seems like I do need to get it from the BuildID. I have the process in place. I think I should be able to post my solution here today.

Comment: Great! Looking forward to the sharing !